# Can QGIS 3.0 be installed and run side-by-side with QGIS 2.x?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, qgis-3, compatibility

I'm interested to know if QGIS 3 can be installed and run side-by-side with a QGIS 2.x installation on windows?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes

## Slightly longer answer

The two applications save all their settings in different places and when they use different versions of the same library, these library versions can safely be installed side-by-side.

**It is encouraged and recommended** to test QGIS 3.x (either current LTR or current release) <strike>(2.99 while there is no official release)</strike> while having a production installations of 2.14 or 2.18 besides to resort to when there are troubles (missing plugins, regressions, ...).

### Caveat: project files

The only possible pitfall is, that QGIS projects saved with 3.0 often do not open properly in 2.18. Meanwhile, projects saved with 2.18 can be opened safely with 3.0. To avoid troubles, always work on copies of your 2.x projects when opening them in 3.0. You should do this anyway when you want to open projects with older QGIS versions later on, also for minor releases.

Comment: Followup q: How?

Comment: You should use the osgeo4w installer and install qgis-dev and qgis-dev-pdb

Comment: For now, you may miss a lot of plugins when running QGIS 2.99 .

Comment: Sorry, I had to make it a little longer to give some context.

Comment: Thanks--I was hoping this was the case and you didn't disappoint!

Comment: And how to do it on Linux?

Comment: I don't know of any packages prepared for this setup. Either use a docker container of QGIS 3 or build it yourself and run it from the build folder or install to custom prefix.

Comment: What about the Python path? QGIS 2.x runs on Python 2.7 while QGIS 3.0 uses Python 3. The result is no Processing module on 3.0.

Comment: @Techie_Gus if you are experiencing problems with processing that's unrelated. The two use completely separated python installations with a different path, so they don't interfere.